# What is the use case of a generic class whose type parameter is itself?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

In which situations would we use the following technique?

```
class A<T>
class B extends A<B> // the B appears twice
```

What are the benefits of such an approach?

For example, I have [seen such a definition](http://jodd.org/api/jodd/http/HttpRequest.html):

```
class HttpBase<T>
```

Then

```
class HttpRequest extends HttpBase<HttpRequest>
```

Also

```
class HttpResponse extends HttpBase<HttpResponse>
```

Comment: Well, in C++ this is called the Curiously Reoccurring Template Pattern. Maybe look into that?